# Why visual studio code is not supporting C++17 whereas I tried changing the version to c++17 and even c++23

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code, c++17

I am trying to run this program which is copied from Learncpp website for learning enum.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string_view> // C++17

enum Color
{
    black,
    red,
    blue,
};

constexpr std::string_view getColor(Color color) // C++17
{
    switch (color)
    {
    case black: return "black";
    case red:   return "red";
    case blue:  return "blue";
    default:    return "???";
    }
}

int main()
{
    Color shirt{ blue };

    std::cout << "Your shirt is " << getColor(shirt) << '\n';

    return 0;
}
```

I am having error like this

```
Practice.cpp:11:16: error: 'string_view' in namespace 'std' does not name a type
   11 | constexpr std::string_view getColor(Color color) // C++17
      |                ^~~~~~~~~~~
Practice.cpp:11:11: note: 'std::string_view' is only available from C++17 onwards
   11 | constexpr std::string_view getColor(Color color) // C++17
      |           ^~~
Practice.cpp: In function 'int main()':
Practice.cpp:26:38: error: 'getColor' was not declared in this scope; did you mean 'Color'?
   26 |     std::cout << "Your shirt is " << getColor(shirt) << '\n';
```

This is my recent setting for the VS code
[image]

Comment: How are you building this?

Comment: You probably need to properly configure it to pass the standard version to the compiler. That's probably just for the IDE. I don't use VScode because of just how barebones it is. If you're not looking for a bare bones IDE i'd pick something besides VScode

Comment: The language standard supported depends on the compiler and version, not on the IDE. If your compiler supports C++17 and C++23, then setting the language standard will work as it simply passes the correct language option as part of the compile string. However, if your compiler does not support the selected language standard, a compiler error will occur and your code should not compile at all.

Comment: The setting you chose is qualified as being used "if `cppStandard` is either not specified or set to `${default}`". It appears to not be used. The [logical conclusion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Contraposition) is that in your project's configuration, `cppStandard` is specified as something other than `${default}`. Have you investigated this?

Comment: I dont know how to do it. The visual studio works great